# Instalação Do iCheck

Tags: javascript, html

Não estou conseguindo fazer o [iCheck](http://fronteed.com/iCheck/) funcionar

eu instalo faço a inclusão dos arquivos css e js no meu index e mesmo assim ele não funciona os checkboxes e os radiobuttons continuam a mesma coisa, alguem pode me ajudar por favor..

na minha head está assim

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="plugins/iCheck/all.css">
```

e os meus checkbox estão assim

```
 <div class="box box-success">
            <div class="box-header">
              <h3 class="box-title">iCheck - Checkbox &amp; Radio Inputs</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="box-body">
              <!-- Minimal style -->

              <!-- checkbox -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" checked>
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="minimal">
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="minimal" disabled>
                  Minimal skin checkbox
                </label>
              </div>

              <!-- radio -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="r1" class="minimal" checked>
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="r1" class="minimal">
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="r1" class="minimal" disabled>
                  Minimal skin radio
                </label>
              </div>

              <!-- Minimal red style -->

              <!-- checkbox -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="minimal-red" checked>
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="minimal-red">
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="minimal-red" disabled>
                  Minimal red skin checkbox
                </label>
              </div>

              <!-- radio -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="r2" class="minimal-red" checked>
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="r2" class="minimal-red">
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="r2" class="minimal-red" disabled>
                  Minimal red skin radio
                </label>
              </div>

              <!-- Minimal red style -->

              <!-- checkbox -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" checked>
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="flat-red">
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="checkbox" class="flat-red" disabled>
                  Flat green skin checkbox
                </label>
              </div>

              <!-- radio -->
              <div class="form-group">
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="r3" class="flat-red" checked>
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="r3" class="flat-red">
                </label>
                <label>
                  <input type="radio" name="r3" class="flat-red" disabled>
                  Flat green skin radio
                </label>
              </div>
            </div><!-- /.box-body -->
            <div class="box-footer">
              Many more skins available. <a href="http://fronteed.com/iCheck/">Documentation</a>
            </div>
          </div><!-- /.box -->
```

Comment: você está importando o arquivo JavaScript no final do `<body>` ?

Comment: Coloco sim, mas mesmo assim ele simplesmente não modifica o checkbox

Comment: E o jQuery ? você está importando ?

Comment: Também estou importando

Comment: Engraçado é que tem uma pagina demo que eu baixei e nela ela funciona normalmente, eu copiei o codigo dela  e não funcionou

Comment: tem algum problema com seu import, olha no console do browser que vocês está usando, está tudo ok ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31892/discussion-between-devgaspa-and-alfredo-lima).

Comment: Algum erro no console?

Comment: @HiagoSouza cara tem alguns erros no console

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ index.php?mod=info-produto:365
morris.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found

Comment: então colega isso é jquery

Answer (score 0):

Conforme informado o erro apresentado é:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ index.php?mod=info-produto:365 morris.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: Graph container element not found
```

Isso ocorre pela falta do jQuery na página, segue abaixo o exemplo de inclusão da biblioteca:

Coloque o código abaixo em baixo da sua tag `<title>...</title>`

```
<title>...</title>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Tentei da forma que você disse e não funcionou

Answer (score 0):

Você está inicializando o iCheck no `input` ? tente isto:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="icheckbox_square-green">

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.icheckbox_square-green').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-green'
  });
});
```

Comment: Também não funcionou